# How to make a Camera Slider with bearings?

Tags: video, camera, diy, gear

I wan't to make a camera slider with bearings that is very smooth. I haven't come up with a good idea yet.

I wan't it to be able to be placed on a tripod. Can you please show me som links and tips and ideas?

Comment: Could you perhaps offer an example of what you're trying to achieve?  Have you run into problems with something you've tried?

Comment: Well, I have looked at this. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nIXDVr-35E But it seems like it is hard to get the metal angels perfect in place. An i would also like the rail to be fastened with a tripod.